# Ordering and grouping in a complex MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, d3.js

I'm needing to do a fairly complex set of MySQL queries to generate data suitable for plotting in D3 from a database of labels assigned to different musical artists. The rows in the relevant table (called "lastfm_annotations") are: user_id, artist_id, tag_id, and tag_month (i.e. we've recorded many instances of a particular user labeling a particular artist with a particular tag at a particular time). This is all embedded in a php script.

What I need to generate in the end is a JSON object that contains, for dates in a given range, the number of times each unique tag for a given artist was used in that month (including counts of zero for dates in which a given tag was not used.

This is what I have so far (assume $itemID and artist_id are interchangeable here):

```
$cal = array();
$result = mysql_query("select date from calendar;");
// this just gets all possible dates, but of course could be changed to get a different date range
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result);  $i++) {
    $date =mysql_fetch_row($result)[0];
    $result2 = mysql_query("select t2.tag_id, case when t1.freq is null then 0 else t1.freq end as freq from (select distinct tag_id from lastfm_annotations where artist_id='" . $itemID . "') t2 left join (select tag_id, count(*) as freq from lastfm_annotations where artist_id='" . $itemID . "' and tag_month='" . $date . "'   group by tag_id) as t1 on t2.tag_id = t1.tag_id group by t2.tag_id");    
    $current = array();
    $current['date'] = $date;
    for ($j = 0; $j < mysql_num_rows($result2); $j++) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result2);
        $tag = $row[0];
        $freq = $row[1];
        $result3 = mysql_query("select tag_name from lastfm_taglist where tag_id ='" . $tag . "' limit 1;");
        $tagName = mysql_fetch_row($result3)[0];
        $current[$tagName] = $freq;
    }
    array_push($data, $current);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

(Edit: the big query follows)

```
select t2.tag_id
     , case 
         when t1.freq is null then 0 
         else t1.freq 
       end as freq 
  from 
       (select distinct tag_id 
          from lastfm_annotations 
         where artist_id='$itemID') t2 
       left join 
       (select tag_id, count(*) as freq 
          from lastfm_annotations 
         where artist_id='$itemID' 
           and tag_month='$date'
         group by tag_id) as t1 
       on t2.tag_id = t1.tag_id 
 group by t2.tag_id
```

(End edit.)

This works, but has (at least) two big problems that I can't quite figure out. First, in big ugly SQL query, I'm doing redundant work calling

```
(select distinct tag_id from lastfm_annotations where artist_id='" . $itemID . "')
```

every time I go through the loop, even though the value is the same every time. Any idea how I can get around that? Maybe it's possible to somehow save the unique tag_ids as a php array, and then insert that into the query?

Second, I need to make sure that the tags are always ordered by their overall frequency (i.e. across all time, not just within a particular month), but I'm not sure how to do that. I can get the proper sequence using a query something like:

```
select tag_id, count(*) as freq from lastfm_annotations where item_id=XXX order by freq desc
```

But I need to ensure that each query in my loop returns the tags in that same order. Any ideas? Perhaps it would be better to handle the sorting in d3 when I actually start plotting data, but it would be preferable if the data started off in the right order when I make the SQL call.

Sorry for the big question, and thanks for any help!

Comment: Thanks for the edit Alanyst - it's much more readable now.

Comment: Side note: you can use the more concise `ifnull(t1.freq, 0)` instead of the `case when t1.freq is null then 0 else t1.freq end` in the query.

Comment: If tag 'foo' is used for artist A in a particular month, but has never been used for artist B, should the results for artist B have rows for tag 'foo' (with `freq` == 0), or should B's results only have tags that have been used for B?

Comment: B's results should only include tags that have been used for artist B (at least once overall). In principal I wouldn't mind having other tags in there with a frequency of zero, but there are on the order of one million unique tags in the DB, so this would make the data structure unreasonably large (and sparse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a query that would be executed once for each artist, rather than each artist-month combination.  It solves your first problem by joining the subqueries on `artist_id` and then filtering on `artist_id = $itemID` in the where clause.  The DB engine should push the condition down into the subqueries when it processes the query, so it won't be as inefficient as it might seem, and since it isn't called inside a month loop it should do less work overall.

The second problem is addressed by getting the overall frequency from the first subquery, and ordering the entire result set by that frequency in descending order.  This will put the most-tagged months first.

The drawback of this is that months with no tags are not represented in the results.  You can get around this in the app logic (for example, by keeping track of which months in your date range haven't been seen for each tag and then synthesizing the '0' rows).  It should also be possible to expand the query to include missing months, but due to complexity I won't get into details on that unless you're interested.

```
select t1.tag_id
     , t2.tag_month
     , t2.freq as month_freq
     , t1.freq as total_freq
  from (select tag_id
             , artist_id
             , count(*) as freq
          from lastfm_annotations
         group by tag_id, artist_id) t1
       inner join
       (select tag_id
             , tag_month
             , artist_id
             , count(*) as freq
          from lastfm_annotations 
         group by tag_id, tag_month, artist_id) t2
       on t1.artist_id = t2.artist_id and t1.tag_id = t2.tag_id
 where t2.tag_month between '$dateRangeStart' and '$dateRangeEnd'
   and t1.artist_id = '$itemID'
 order by total_freq desc, t1.tag_id
```

Comment: This seems to work nicely - thanks! The only edit I made was to also order by tag_month, but that's a pretty trivial change. My only concern is execution time...I ran this with one arbitrary artist ID, and it took on the order of 2hrs to generate a result... My goal was to deploy this in an interactive visualization tool, but that's not really possible with that kind of execution time. Still accepting, as it did answer all my questions. Any thoughts on the execution time issue would be appreciated, though.

Comment: What indexes are on the tables?

Comment: Composite primary key on user_id+item_id+tag_id, plus (non-unique) indexes on item_id, artist_id, tag_id, and tag_month. Some of this may be redundant, as I've been tweaking the DB structure for some time. To clarify things, each item (album, artist, or song) has a unique ID, but each annotation (instance of tagging an item) has an associated artist_id. Here are screenshots of the db structure that should make things clearer: [indexes](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/625604/indexes.PNG), [table structure](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/625604/tableStructure.PNG).

Comment: Oh, and you can ignore the "tag_date" column. Only "tag_month" is being used. Keep in mind the table has on the order of 50 million entries total.